# Frame drops with multiple ScrollView items (app freezes)

Tags: react-native

I am having some known problems with multiple `ScrollView` elements on a single page.

Consider this wireframe as my application:

[image]

On each Carousel I have an `onScroll` event being fired, this is to work out the current *active* item (which then used for pagination).

What is happening is that when the app loads, I can scroll through some carousels but after approximately 30 seconds, everything freezes. I can't scroll any carousel, nor can I scroll the vertical ScrollView.

Comment: Infinite scroll? Try `FlatList`.

Comment: So would I convert my carousel `FlatList`?

Comment: are you trying to create infinite scrolling or do you want it to reach the end of the list?

Comment: So my problem @riwu is that when I use multiple ScrollViews, the app freezes. I am unable to Scroll anymore when it freezes. I;m not bothered about infinite scroll.

Comment: How many Carousels do you have? Try use `FlatList` to render the list of Carousels.